# How to terminate or transition starlink cable out of conduit

Tags: electrical, conduit, network

[image]I’ve got low voltage starlink cable through conduit coming out of 1” liquid tite conduit to then wrap around a wall before coming into the house.(see pic)  The conduit is too large and unsightly to bring around so just want this small run exposed. BUT, what’s the best way to transition the conduit to wire? I can’t dissamble the cable. I don’t want rodents or other critters getting up the conduit.

Comment: Duct seal compound.  Or get a conduit cap, drill a hole in it for the cable, cut it in half, reassemble around the cable, and glue in place (seal around cable with polyurethane caulk or aforementioned duct seal).

Comment: *just want this small run exposed* Not a good idea. Code-wise it is OK because it is low voltage. But critter-wise it isn't a great idea. In any case, why can't you dissasemble the cable? What type of cable is it? Can usually tell by a combination of markings on the cable and the connector on the end. Or possibly in the user's manual.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I believe Starlink includes a outdoor and UV rated Ethernet cable with molded ends, which is the cable in question here.

Comment: It is a Starlink cable and it is NOT dissasembleable without significant issues and well above my skill set. And because in their infinite wisdom designed the ends to be unidirectional in the way you can pull them and even then have to use 1" conduit for such a small wire. Wife doesn't want a big 1" whip pulled around that corner and in the front of the house before it ducks inside...

Comment: It's worse than that -- the Starlink cable uses proprietary connectors so you can't even get a keystone bulkhead jack for it...

Comment: Yeah, this builds a case for diversity at tech companies. Most of these employees are young urbanized or suburban youth that have never worked in the trades or done much with their hands. They design things that are install UNFRIENDLY such as this situation. Turns out diversity means more than sexual orientation or ethnicity! get it together tech people... (since I'm on a rant, i;m pretty sure the apple people that designed touch id never worked with their hands enough to understand that at times your fingers will not work in this manner...)